# Is it a good practice to evaluate model performance by comparing the metrics of rescaled (inverse transformed) predictions and true target values?

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, model-evaluations, model-selection, feature-scaling

I am now working with a Linear Regression for a time-series regression problem (I am sorry that I cannot say too much about the problem and feature vector due to NDA).

I scaled **both** the input values and target (X and y) with scikit-learn StandardScaler(). 
The reasoning of scaling both X and y because since it is a time series regression problem, we are using the previous y value (target value) as the feature (X) for the next datapoint. 
Thus, there is a relation between y and X. 
So, I thought that in order to maintain the dependence of X and y (the previous target value), I need to scale them both.

After training the model, I got a low RMSE on my validation and test sets. Note that, the validation and test sets contain the data with scaled/normalized X and y values.

However, when I tried to rescale (inverse_transform) the predictions, and evaluate the RMSE of the predictions against the true target value of the test set (the true target value is already rescaled as well), I got a high RMSE error.

My question is, is it a good practice to evaluate RMSE/accuracy of rescaled (inverse transformed) predictions against the true target values?

Answer (score 0):

The error as a percentage of the true value in each case is probably the same - it just seems bigger because the standardised values are a lot smaller than the unstandardised ones (standardised values will be mostly between -1 and 1 and the unstandardised values will be whatever they are in your dataset).

Try measuring the fit of your linear model using [Pearson’s correlation coefficient](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-correlation-to-understand-the-relationship-between-variables/), checking how your predicted values correlate to the true values. This should be the same for both the scaled and unscaled cases and will give you a better idea of whether your model is good.

You could also plot your predicted values against the true values in a scatter plot so that you can see roughly what’s going on.

Comment: [Correlation between predictions and true values is a surprisingly problematic measure of performance.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/114457/73930)