# What are the pros and cons of R2 (coefficient of determination)?

Tags: regression, statistics, linear-regression

What are the pros and cons of $R^2$ (coefficient of determination) which is an evaluation metric?

Comment: Compared to what? // [Related](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/114457/73930), depending on how you calculate $R^2$. // How would you calculate $R^2?$ [I’ve seen at least four ways.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/590199/247274)

Comment: I checked the link you sent but I Could not see it’s Pros and Cons. I just wanna know it’s general Pros and Cons. 

Let me give a advantage as example  is It’s most popular Regression metric and it is Easy to understand as well as computationally simple.

Comment: One of those links gives at least four ways to calculate $R^2$. Which way would you be using?